# Dynamically selecting which struct to use while scanning from mysql row database/sql

Tags: go

I have a table where it can hold different settings in some json column. I want to parse that column to struct while calling `Scan` on row.

Here is what models look like.

```
type ServerConfig interface {
    Scan(value interface{}) error
}

type SystemSettings struct {
    SystemId    int64
    SystemName  string
    Settings    ServerConfig
}

type SoapConfig struct {
    Username string `json:"username"`
    Password string `json:"password"`
    Tenant   string `json:"tenant"`
    BaseUrl  string `json:"baseUrl"`
}

func (m *SoapConfig) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    b, ok := value.([]byte)
    if !ok {
        return errors.New("type assertion to []byte failed")
    }
    return json.Unmarshal(b, &m)
}

type RestConfig struct {
    Endpoint string `json:"endpoint"`
    Token    string `json:"token"`
}

func (m *RestConfig) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    b, ok := value.([]byte)
    if !ok {
        return errors.New("type assertion to []byte failed")
    }
    return json.Unmarshal(b, &m)
}
```

In repository I want to use it like this

```
  ...query stuff
    config := &model.SystemSettings{}
    config.Settings := &SoapConfig{}

    if err = row.Scan(
        &config.SystemId,
        &config.SystemName,
        &config.Settings,

    ); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return config, nil
```

I am having problems on scanning the `ServerConfig` for the specific implementation. I want to be able to dynamically define struct for scanning depending on the `systemName`.

```
Scan error on column index 3, name \"server_config\": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type []uint8 into type *model.ServerConfig"
```

I am getting this error which kinda makes sense. Is there any way I can achieve what I want?

Comment: `&config.Settings` -> `config.Settings`. The `Setting` field is an interface that __already__ holds a pointer to the concrete type, so `&` is unnecessary. Furthermore  `ServerConfig` is an interface and an interface's methods are not accessible through a pointer directly, so `*ServerConfig` does not have access to `Scan` and therefore the `ServerConfig.Scan` method will not be invoked.

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/dpL5uiojgmt -- You almost _never_ want to use pointers to interfaces.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out as well. removing `&` makes it ok since we already have a pointer for the destination struct as you already mentioned, thanks for the input. Now I am wondering if this is the best way to achieve this because we will need some switch cases for each different config